# CakePHP drop down box from associated model

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple api that allows customers to book vehicles. In my reservations controller i have a function which is to add a reservation. Here is the code:

**Controller**

```
    function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Reservation->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Reservation was successfully added!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Reservation was not added.');
            }
        }
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Add Reservation');
    }
```

Here is what i have in my add view for a reservation.

**View**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Reservation', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array( 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input('vehicle_id', array( 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input('date');
echo $this->Form->end('Add Reservation');
?>
```

But because i am adding a new reservation and i want a dropdown box for vehicle ids and one for customer ids how can i do this?

I think i have linked the models by putting this into the customers and vehicles models:

```
var $hasMany = array( 'Reservation' => array( 'className' => 'Reservation' ) );
```

Could anyone point me into the right direction so that a dropdown box would appear with a list of vehicle and customer IDs on the add reservation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your add function in controller, use

```
$vehicle = $this->Reservation->Vehicle->find('list', array('fields' =>array('Vehicle.id','Vehicle.name')));                               
$this->set('vehicle', $vehicle);
```

In your view,use

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('vehicle_id', array('type' => 'select',
                                                  'options' => $vehicle)); ?>
```

Use the same thing for customers also and you will get list of customers and vehicles in dropdown.

Comment: It would be easier to name the variable `vehicles`. By convention, the `vehicle_id` dropdown will then automagically be populated with those values, without having to specify the `options` option.